# How to obtain priority gas price in ETH with web3 version > 1.x.x?

Tags: web3js

I previously used the `getFeeHistory` method with web3js version 1.x.x to obtain priority gas prices. After updating to versions 3.x.x or 4.x.x, I noticed this method is no longer available, with only `getGasPrice` being present. I attempted to construct a new method using web3-core, but it appears there's no built-in method to accomplish this task.

1. How can the priority gas price be retrieved from the blockchain using these newer versions of web3?
2. Why was the getFeeHistory method removed, and are there any recommended alternatives to achieve the same functionality without simulating a transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the fee history using the [eth_feeHistory](https://www.quicknode.com/docs/ethereum/eth_feeHistory) JSON-RPC method in web3.js, even if there isn't a wrapper function for this request built into the library for versions 3 or 4. Here's how you can make this custom request:

```js
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('YOUR_PROVIDER_URL');

web3.currentProvider.send(
  {
    jsonrpc: '2.0',
    method: 'eth_feeHistory',
    params: [blockCount, newestBlock, rewardPercentiles],
    id: new Date().getTime()
  },
  (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } else {
      console.log(result);
    }
  }
);
```